# Set Focus to an Element from code behind after submit in the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to set focus to an element (a button) after the user clicks on Submit, but the focus is not on a new page it is in the same page. What is happening is that when they click submit i am evaluating a few conditions.. if one of them is met I send them back to the same page (or do not re-direct) in other terms but it still postsback so, when it postsback I again after the submit, i want to set the focus to this item.. how can i do this?

Comment: How about if my control has a Tab index? how can i do something like if(blah == true) gotoTabIndex = 3;  ... possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to set the focus of the page to a WebControl on the page? i.e. a `<asp:Button>`?

You can use `ControlId.Focus()`

EDIT

If you are talking about the Scroll position after postback, then you could try this

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Now I have never used it before or tried it, so not sure if it works.

Comment: Yeah but when I do this... the page is still loading and momentarily it shows the item focused but then it goes back to the top of the page...

Comment: what do you mean by "it goes back to the top of the page"? what does? the focus? what does it focus on? Are you talking about the Scroll position of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Despite your question doesn't seem too clear to me, I am assuming that you want to set focus to the asp.net control, so you can do

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           if(vartemp === vartemp2) //assuming that you want to set focus when specific condition meets
             myButton1.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah but when I do this... the page is still loading and momentarily it shows the item focused but then it goes back to the top of the page... - Sorry the question is not too clear but yes you understood it well

Answer (score 0):

Use a hiddenfield and set its value with the controlId of the control you are validating before making the postback. and in the pageload event you can check the value of the hidden field and focus that control.

Or you can use validationcontrols for validating.